# NetBSD 'pkg_add' can't process packages: Forbidden

Tags: package, netbsd, pkgsrc

I'm new to using NetBSD but I've set it up on a VM and am currently in the process of running through a few package installations. From what I understand this is done via setting the PKG_PATH variable and then using the *pkg_add* utility, however I'm getting a "Forbidden" error message when I try to install any package.

**$ PKG_PATH="http://cdn.NetBSD.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/$(uname -s)/$(uname -m)/$(uname -r|cut -f '1 2' -d.)/All/"

$ export PKG_PATH

$ pkg_add tmux

pkg_add: Can't process http://cdn.NetBSD.org:80/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/amd64                                       /7.1/All//tmux*: Forbidden

pkg_add: no pkg found for 'tmux', sorry.

pkg_add: 1 package addition failed**

I've visited the URL and the package does exist, also it does this for any package I try to install. From what I can tell the networking on the machine is fine so I'm a bit stuck as to where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the error message you quote, there appears to be a space between the machine architecture and the OS version.  Can you verify that your PKG_PATH variable lacks a space there? If there is a space, remove it and try again.

Comment: No space in the path - it just formatted it weird. To verify, if I echo $PKG_PATH, I get:http://cdn.NetBSD.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/amd64/7.1/All/

Comment: The error message isn't very helpful, but `Forbidden` in that context means that the web server returned a 403 error.  I can't guess why though.  As a work-around you can fetch the file using some other means then use `pkg_add` with the local pathname.  Using `ftp` from that system to try to fetch the file with that same URL (but with the pathname `tmux-2.3nb2.tgz` appended of course) may provide additional diagnostics.

Comment: Ah perfect, I'd been trying to workaround by downloading the files on my own machine and then moving them over but since they were tgz files I was unzipping them normally rather than using pkg_add for some reason. That seems to have done the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue but instead of forbidden, I got "Unknown HTTP error"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ApHZ.jpg)
My solution was changing from "http**s**" to "http" and it worked for me. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

On NetBSD 9.3 (guest) inside the virtual Machine qemu on Gentoo with kernel version 9.1-19 (host),
I got a similar issue but instead of "forbidden", I got "Timeout on HTTPS"-
Again change https -> http worked for me, as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) try $PKG_PATH without the trailing slash, i.e. .../All instead of .../All/
2) "tmux*" doesn't make sense for http, it only makes sense for ftp. something seems fishy.

I recommend raising this on tech-pkg@NetBSD.org